# Unable to find NinjectWcfApplication reference when try to install nInject for WCF

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection, ninject, ninject-extensions, ninject.web

I want to add nInject into WCF service and i followed below steps.
http://www.aaronstannard.com/post/2011/08/16/dependency-injection-ninject-wcf-service.aspx

Problem: I am not able to find `NinjectWcfApplication` class to inherit for global.asax.

Kindly let me know which module i have to add so, i could find `NinjectWcfApplication` class and able to inject into wcf service class.

Added - `ninject.extensions.wcf` nuget package. 
`<package id="Ninject" version="3.2.2.0" targetFramework="net40" />`
`<package id="Ninject.Extensions.Wcf" version="3.2.1.0" targetFramework="net40" />`

Please guide me how to resolve this.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I believe that not have more this class. After adding the Ninject.Extensions.Wcf extent and factory in the service, add the nuget dependencies:

1. Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure
2. WebActivatorEx.

Once this is done, create a NinjectWebCommon class, similar to the MVC. For me it worked that way.

Good luck.